# Jquery Ajax - Submitting form with ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form which on submit I want to run a script via Ajax, but for some reason it is returning an error. Any idea what is wrong? My code is as following:

```
$('.spiderform').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://spidertest.epiphanydev1.co.uk/spider/?'+$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert('sending form');
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('worked');
            },
            error: function(jon) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post the error you get?

Comment: How do I get what the error is?

Comment: use firebug to see the error, open its console and try to submit the form. The error will be displayed in firebug console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't given any idea *what* error is is, but since you have an absolute URI in there, I'd guess you are running into the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Yes the URL i'm sending to is on a different server than the one I'm making the call from. How would I achieve the results I'm after?

Comment: Probocop, submit it server-side. Your ajax submit it to php/servlet/cgi, and then php/servlet submit it to the intended server.

Comment: That's exactly what I've just ended up doing :)